# How do I prolong the longevity of my MacBook's internal SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, hardware

I have a MacBook Pro with a 500GB NVMe internal drive. According to [this website](https://www.enterprisestorageforum.com/storage-hardware/ssd-lifespan.html), the Samsung 850 Pro is under warranty until 300 TBW for a 512 GB drive. Other sources (less conservatively) report double the lifetime of an NVMe to be [about 700 TBW](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/06/consumer-grade-ssds-actually-last-a-hell-of-a-long-time/).

I have been monitoring my disk usage for a while now. In the last ten days of uptime, my disk usage has been around 10 TBW and 9 TBR. That means about 1 TB of data is read and written per day. Extrapolating and taking the best case scenario my internal drive would last a maximum of two years before dying. Given that the internal drive can't be replaced, obviously I'm very concerned with my data usage because I expect a Mac to last me at least five years.

What is causing this high amount of data usage, and how do I reduce it to prolong the life of my internal SSD?

**Activity Monitor**

[image]

Trying to understand this usage, I took a look at Activity Monitor. Why has kernel_task written nearly 10 TB to my disk? Why has Brave and Mail read nearly a third of a terabyte of data from my disk? Is there any way I can stop that from happening (apart from "not using them")?

**Usage Characteristics**

I use my Mac for photo editing, video editing, light gaming, as well as using tools such as Mathematica, Python, Handbrake, and various command line tools. I generally have ~25 apps running that I use regularly and switch between throughout the day. These apps include Safari, where I am generally active on about 10-30 tabs throughout the day, and Brave, where I am active on ~10 tabs throughout the day.

Answer (score 2):

I'm speculating that kernel_task's write may be a result of swap memory, so your 'fix' might be to not run so many things at once.

As to the rest, I'd simply stop worrying about it.

My oldest Samsung SSD has been running 24/7 since 2014 & has yet to show any sign of age. In fact the only failed SSD in the building was a cheap generic 128GB drive which gave up the ghost after about a year of not particularly hard work. All the others are still going, various ages from 1 to 6 years.

Comment: But I'm presuming you don't read and write 1 TB *daily* to your disk! I can't imagine most of this would be from swapping. If you have a Samsung SSD, I'm presuming you're talking about an external drive. I'm not worried at all about my external drives failing, it's just that I realize 1 TB (which is twice my drive size) is a *massive* amount

Comment: The thing is, I understand that the vast majority of Mac users are writing probably a maximum of 40-50 GB to the disk daily, and they don't need to worry at all. My use case calls for 20x as much, so quite regrettably I *do* need to worry about the lifetime of my SSD. Unless perhaps you can show me that an Apple NVMe has an endurance of 2000 TBW, I have to be worried about my drive being the limit to my Mac's longevity

Comment: i'm down to about 500GB/day these days, doing a bit of photography work, but the first 2014 SSD mentioned above used to be massively higher than that. I ran it on an audio workstation, day in day out, sometimes pieces with 100 audio tracks running simultaneously, whilst recording more each pass.